# Validate and save dynamically added fields to DB using MVC and Javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, formvalidation.io

I'm trying to validate dynamically added fields and saving to DB. Formvalidation is working but when I submit the form to controller model.Count is not changing.(Model.Count = 1)

I believe problem is simple but some reason I don't see the problem.
I'm waiting for your help.

Also you can see working example and debug screenshots.

Edit

[In this screenshot you can see client page,debug mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R10XF.jpg)

Model

```
    public int BudgetId { get; set; }
    public int DistributionId { get; set; }
    public int InvoiceId { get; set; }
    public bool ExtraBudgetary { get; set; }
    public string ExtraBudgetaryNo { get; set; }
    public string Currency { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public decimal CurrencyRate { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public bool DistributionTemp { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public decimal ActualAmount { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public decimal Percentage { get; set; }
    public DateTime TransactionDate { get; set; }
    public string DistributionName { get; set; }
    public int ProcessedBy { get; set; }
    public string Explanation { get; set; }
    public bool Validity { get; set; }
```

View

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <section class="panel panel-default">
            <header class="panel-heading">
                <i class="fa fa-bolt"></i>
                Actions
                <span class="tools pull-right">
                    <a href="javascript:;" class="fa fa-chevron-down"></a>
                    <a href="javascript:;" class="fa fa-cog"></a>
                    <a href="javascript:;" class="fa fa-times"></a>
                </span>
            </header>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <a href="/Budget/Home/Index" class="btn btn-white btn-danger btn-round btn-xs">
                    <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
                    Close
                </a>
                <button class="btn btn-white btn-success btn-round btn-xs" type="submit" tabindex="14" value="Create">
                    <i class="fa fa-floppy-o bigger-120 green"></i>
                    Save
                </button>
            </div>
        </section>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <section class="panel panel-success">
            <header class="panel-heading">
                <i class="fa fa-credit-card"></i>
                New Actual(s)
                <span class="tools pull-right">
                    <a href="javascript:;" class="fa fa-chevron-down"></a>
                    <a href="javascript:;" class="fa fa-cog"></a>
                    <a href="javascript:;" class="fa fa-times"></a>
                </span>
            </header>
            <div class="panel-body" style="overflow-x: scroll;">
                <div class="pull-left">
                    <br />
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-white btn-success btn-round btn-xs addButton"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></button>
                    <div class="">

                        @if (Model != null && Model.Count > 0)
                        {
                            int j = 0;
                            foreach (var i in Model)
                            {

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class="col-xs-2">
                                        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m[j].BudgetId, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.BudgetId, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-xs-1">
                                        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m[j].InvoiceId, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.InvoiceId, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-xs-1">
                                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m[j].ActualAmount, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Actual Amount" })
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-xs-1">
                                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m[j].Percentage, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Percentage" })
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-xs-1">
                                        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m[j].ExtraBudgetary, new SelectList(Enum.GetValues(typeof(TrueFalse))), htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Is ExtraBudgetary ?" })
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-xs-2">
                                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m[j].ExtraBudgetaryNo, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "ExtraBudgetary No" })
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-xs-1">
                                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m[j].CurrencyRate, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Currency Rate" })
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-xs-2">
                                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m[j].Description, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Description" })
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group hide" id="actualTemplate">
                                    <div class="col-xs-2">
                                        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m[j].BudgetId, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.BudgetId, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-xs-1">
                                        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m[j].InvoiceId, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.InvoiceId, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-xs-1">
                                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m[j].ActualAmount, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Actual Amount" })
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-xs-1">
                                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m[j].Percentage, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Percentage" })
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-xs-1">
                                        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m[j].ExtraBudgetary, new SelectList(Enum.GetValues(typeof(TrueFalse))), htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Is ExtraBudgetary ?" })
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-xs-2">
                                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m[j].ExtraBudgetaryNo, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "ExtraBudgetary No" })
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-xs-1">
                                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m[j].CurrencyRate, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Currency Rate" })
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-xs-2">
                                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m[j].Description, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Description" })
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-xs-1">
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-white btn-danger btn-round btn-xs removeButton"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i></button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                j++;
                            }
                        }

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        budgetIdValidators = {
            row: '.col-xs-2',   
            validators: {
                notEmpty: {
                    message: 'The budget Id is required'
                },
                numeric: {
                    message: 'The budget Id must be a numeric number'
                }
            }
        },
        invoiceIdValidators = {
            row: '.col-xs-1',   
            validators: {
                notEmpty: {
                    message: 'The invoice Id is required'
                },
                numeric: {
                    message: 'The invoice Id must be a numeric number'
                }
            }
        },
        actualAmountValidators = {
            row: '.col-xs-1',   
            validators: {
                notEmpty: {
                    message: 'The actual amount is required'
                },
                numeric: {
                    message: 'The actual amount must be a numeric number'
                }
            }
        },
        percentageValidators = {
            row: '.col-xs-1',
            validators: {
                notEmpty: {
                    message: 'The percentage is required'
                },
                numeric: {
                    message: 'The percentage must be a numeric number'
                }
            }
        },
        extraBudgetaryValidators = {
            row: '.col-xs-1',
            validators: {
                notEmpty: {
                    message: 'The extrabudgetary is required'
                }
            }
        },
        extraBudgetaryNoValidators = {
            row: '.col-xs-2',
            validators: {
                notEmpty: {
                    message: 'The extrabudgetary no is required'
                }
            }
        },
        currencyRateValidators = {
            row: '.col-xs-1',
            validators: {
                notEmpty: {
                    message: 'The currency rate is required'
                },
                numeric: {
                    message: 'The currency rate must be a numeric number'
                }
            }
        },
        descriptionValidators = {
            row: '.col-xs-2',
            validators: {
                notEmpty: {
                    message: 'The description is required'
                }
            }
        },
        actualIndex = 0;

        $('#actualsCreateForm')
            .formValidation({
                framework: 'bootstrap',
                icon: {
                    valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
                    invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
                    validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
                },
                fields: {
                    '[0].BudgetId': budgetIdValidators,
                    '[0].InvoiceId': invoiceIdValidators,
                    '[0].ActualAmount': actualAmountValidators,
                    '[0].Percentage': percentageValidators,
                    '[0].ExtraBudgetary': extraBudgetaryValidators,
                    '[0].ExtraBudgetaryNo': extraBudgetaryNoValidators,
                    '[0].CurrencyRate': currencyRateValidators,
                    '[0].Description': descriptionValidators,
                }
            })

            .on('click', '.addButton', function () {
                actualIndex++;
                var $template = $('#actualTemplate'),
                    $clone = $template
                                    .clone()
                                    .removeClass('hide')
                                    .removeAttr('id')
                                    .attr('data-actual-index', actualIndex)
                                    .insertBefore($template);

                $clone
                    .find('[name="BudgetId"]').attr('name', '[' + actualIndex + '].BudgetId').end()
                    .find('[name="InvoiceId"]').attr('name', '[' + actualIndex + '].InvoiceId').end()
                    .find('[name="ActualAmount"]').attr('name', '[' + actualIndex + '].ActualAmount').end()
                    .find('[name="Percentage"]').attr('name', '[' + actualIndex + '].Percentage').end()
                    .find('[name="ExtraBudgetary"]').attr('name', '[' + actualIndex + '].ExtraBudgetary').end()
                    .find('[name="ExtraBudgetaryNo"]').attr('name', '[' + actualIndex + '].ExtraBudgetaryNo').end()
                    .find('[name="CurrencyRate"]').attr('name', '[' + actualIndex + '].CurrencyRate').end()
                    .find('[name="Description"]').attr('name', '[' + actualIndex + '].Description').end();

                $('#actualsCreateForm')
                    .formValidation('addField', '[' + actualIndex+ '].BudgetId', budgetIdValidators)
                    .formValidation('addField', '[' + actualIndex+ '].InvoiceId', invoiceIdValidators)
                    .formValidation('addField', '[' + actualIndex+ '].ActualAmount', actualAmountValidators)
                    .formValidation('addField', '[' + actualIndex+ '].Percentage', percentageValidators)
                    .formValidation('addField', '[' + actualIndex+ '].ExtraBudgetary', extraBudgetaryValidators)
                    .formValidation('addField', '[' + actualIndex+ '].ExtraBudgetaryNo', extraBudgetaryNoValidators)
                    .formValidation('addField', '[' + actualIndex+ '].CurrencyRate', currencyRateValidators)
                    .formValidation('addField', '[' + actualIndex+ '].Description', descriptionValidators);
            })
            .on('click', '.removeButton', function () {
                var $row = $(this).parents('.form-group'),
                    index = $row.attr('data-actual-index');

                $('#actualsCreateForm')
                    .formValidation('removeField', $row.find('[name="[' + index + '].BudgetId"]'))
                    .formValidation('removeField', $row.find('[name="[' + index + '].InvoiceId"]'))
                    .formValidation('removeField', $row.find('[name="[' + index + '].ActualAmount"]'))
                    .formValidation('removeField', $row.find('[name="[' + index + '].Percentage"]'))
                    .formValidation('removeField', $row.find('[name="[' + index + '].ExtraBudgetary"]'))
                    .formValidation('removeField', $row.find('[name="[' + index + '].ExtraBudgetaryNo"]'))
                    .formValidation('removeField', $row.find('[name="[' + index + '].CurrencyRate"]'))
                    .formValidation('removeField', $row.find('[name="[' + index + '].Description"]'));

                $row.remove();
            })

            .on('err.field.fv', function (e, data) {
                data.element
                    .data('fv.messages')
                    .find('.help-block[data-fv-for="' + data.field + '"]').hide();
            });
    });
</script>
```

Controller

```
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var status = statusRepository.FindByName("In Process of Actualization");
            var user = userRepository.FindByName(SessionPersister.Username);
            foreach (var i in acVM)
            {
                var invoice = invoiceRepository.FindById(i.InvoiceId);
                Actual actual = new Actual
                {
                    BudgetId = i.BudgetId,
                    InvoiceId = i.InvoiceId,
                    ActualAmount = i.ActualAmount,
                    ExtraBudgetary = i.ExtraBudgetary,
                    ExtraBudgetaryNo = i.ExtraBudgetaryNo,
                    TransactionDate = DateTime.Now,
                    Currency = "USD",
                    CurrencyRate = i.CurrencyRate,
                    Description = i.Description,
                    //DistributionTemp = i.DistributionTemp,
                    Percentage = i.Percentage
                };
                actualRepository.Create(actual);

                if (actual != null)
                {
                    if (i.DistributionTemp == true)
                    {
                        DistributionTemplate distributionTemp = new DistributionTemplate
                        {
                            DistributionName = i.DistributionName,
                            Percentage = i.Percentage,
                            ProcessedBy = user.UserId,
                            Explanation = i.Description,
                            Validity = i.Validity,
                            ActualAmount = actual.ActualAmount,
                            TransactionDate = DateTime.Now
                        };
                        distributionTempRepository.Create(distributionTemp);
                        if (distributionTemp != null)
                        {
                            actual.DistributionId = distributionTemp.DistributionId;
                            actualRepository.Update(actual);
                        }
                    }

                    Process process = new Process
                    {
                        InvoiceId = i.InvoiceId,
                        StatusId = status.StatusId,
                        ProcessedBy = user.UserId,
                        ProcessDate = DateTime.Now,
                        //Confirmatory = relatedUnitManager.UnitId
                    };
                    processRepository.Create(process); // Yapılan işlemin kaydedilmesi

                    ViewBag.BudgetId = new SelectList(budgetRepository.SelectBudgets(), "BudgetId", "BudgetId", i.BudgetId);
                    ViewBag.DistributionId = new SelectList(distributionTempRepository.SelectDistributions(), "DistributionId", "DistributionName", i.DistributionId);
                    ViewBag.InvoiceId = new SelectList(invoiceRepository.SelectInvoices(), "InvoiceId", "InvoiceNo", i.InvoiceId);

                    if (process != null)
                    {
                        invoice.LastProcessId = process.ProcessId;
                        invoiceRepository.Update(invoice); // Yapılan son işleme dair id bilgisinin fatura tablosuna eklenmesi
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    TempData["MessageFail"] += "Something went wrong!";
                    return RedirectToAction("Details/" + invoice.InvoiceId, "Invoices");
                }
                acVM = new List<ActualizationVM> { new ActualizationVM { ExtraBudgetary = false, ExtraBudgetaryNo = "", BudgetId = 0, InvoiceId = 0, Description = "", ActualAmount = 0, Percentage = 0, CurrencyRate = 0} };
                TempData["MessageSuccess"] += "Invoice is successfully actualized.";
                return RedirectToAction("Details/" + invoice.InvoiceId, "Invoices");
            }
        }
        return View(acVM);
```

Edit 2

When I update the naming like following naming clone is worked fine but when I submit the form count is still not increasing

```
$clone
                    .find('[name="[' + actualIndex + '].BudgetId"]').attr('name', '[' + actualIndex + '].BudgetId').end()
                    .find('[name="[' + actualIndex + '].InvoiceId"]').attr('name', '[' + actualIndex + '].InvoiceId').end()
                    .find('[name="[' + actualIndex + '].ActualAmount"]').attr('name', '[' + actualIndex + '].ActualAmount').end()
                    .find('[name="[' + actualIndex + '].Percentage"]').attr('name', '[' + actualIndex + '].Percentage').end()
                    .find('[name="[' + actualIndex + '].ExtraBudgetary"]').attr('name', '[' + actualIndex + '].ExtraBudgetary').end()
                    .find('[name="[' + actualIndex + '].ExtraBudgetaryNo"]').attr('name', '[' + actualIndex + '].ExtraBudgetaryNo').end()
                    .find('[name="[' + actualIndex + '].CurrencyRate"]').attr('name', '[' + actualIndex + '].CurrencyRate').end()
                    .find('[name="[' + actualIndex + '].Description"]').attr('name', '[' + actualIndex + '].Description').end();
```

Comment: You seem to be adding the items to the repositories ok, but where are you saving the changes to the context? E.g. if you were using DbContext you would be using DbContext.Save();

Comment: I'am using concrete class who implements related interface. This is my save method in ActualRepository.cs                                          BudgetContext context = new BudgetContext();
        public void Create(Actual a)
        {
            context.Actuals.Add(a);
            context.SaveChanges();
        }

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is incorrect:

```
$clone
                    .find('[name="BudgetId"]').attr('name', '[' + actualIndex + '].BudgetId').end()
                    .find('[name="InvoiceId"]').attr('name', '[' + actualIndex + '].InvoiceId').end()
                    .find('[name="ActualAmount"]').attr('name', '[' + actualIndex + '].ActualAmount').end()
                    .find('[name="Percentage"]').attr('name', '[' + actualIndex + '].Percentage').end()
                    .find('[name="ExtraBudgetary"]').attr('name', '[' + actualIndex + '].ExtraBudgetary').end()
                    .find('[name="ExtraBudgetaryNo"]').attr('name', '[' + actualIndex + '].ExtraBudgetaryNo').end()
                    .find('[name="CurrencyRate"]').attr('name', '[' + actualIndex + '].CurrencyRate').end()
                    .find('[name="Description"]').attr('name', '[' + actualIndex + '].Description').end();
```

I am unsure about the correct "naming" to bind elements, even though I've had trouble with that before. My approach was to increase my original list, loop through it, and then copy the way the binding is done exactly as it is.

Comment: When I update the naming like following naming clone is worked fine but when I  submit the form count is still not increasing   ;  **`.find('[name="[' + actualIndex + '].BudgetId"]').attr('name', '[' + actualIndex + '].BudgetId').end() `**